Flutter Physical Back Button Pop Navigation not working Popscope
demo video of error :  Video Drive link
I my app I want that on physical back button clicked I want to show dialog, as in the video in start on cllicking the back button of app bar,
but when I am clicking physical back button screen is getting poped and than showing the dialog,
below is my code
return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: ((didPop) async {
        if (didPop) {
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
          await willPopConfirmation(context);
          return;
        }
        if (context.mounted) {
          Routemaster.of(context).pop();
        }
      }),
      child: Scaffold(

// Seacond method I've tried 
 return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: ((didPop) async {
        if (didPop) {
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
          await willPopConfirmation(context);
          if (context.mounted) {
            Routemaster.of(context).pop();
          }
          return;
        }
      }),


I mean whatever I do, firstly It's getting pop than showing the dialog, and if I remove that  Future.delayed();  than I am getting error
e 4203 pos 12: '_debugLocked && !_debugUpdatingPage': is not true.
because It is not staying on the screen it is immeidatly poping
my dialog code : --
Future<void> willPopConfirmation(BuildContext context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Save Draft?'),
        content: const Text('Do you want to save the draft or discard it?'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              deleteDraft(); // Handle draft deletion (not shown)
              Navigator.pop(context); // Exit confirmed
            },
            child: const Text('Discard'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              saveDraft(); 
              Navigator.pop(context); 
            },
            child: const Text('Save'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

I have used evry simple dialoge as well but didn't worked
return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: ((didPop) async {
        if (didPop) {
          await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
          await willPopConfirmation(context);
          return;
        }
        if (context.mounted) {
          Routemaster.of(context).pop();
        }
      }),
      child: Scaffold(



not need to use "delayed(), async and await" just check didpop is false, if false then call willPopConfirmation() method.
i'm take one variable named isPoped.
when dialog is open and tap to "Discard" or "Save" button then the isPoped is true and pop the dialog and current screen if user tap outside the dialog or ignore the dialog then isPoped value is false and it pop the only dialog not screen.
see below code for better understanding.


  //take variable
  bool isPoped = false;

  //show dialog method
  Future<void> willPopConfirmation(context) async {
    await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Save Draft?'),
        content: const Text('Do you want to save the draft or discard it?'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              isPoped = true;
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text('Discard'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              isPoped = true;
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text('Save'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

    // use it in build() method
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: ((didPop) async {
       if (!didPop) await willPopConfirmation(context); //call the function
       if (context.mounted && isPoped) Navigator.pop(context);
      }),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text("pop scope"),
        ),
      ),
    );

